# Prefer file types in command line

Tags: bash, files, zsh

Often I have to annotate multiple pdf documents using `xournal`. If I start with a directory of "fresh" `pdf` files, I just open them all with `xournal`:

```
for f in *pdf; do xournal $f&; done
```

When I begin to annotate a file, say a `.pdf` I save it as a `.xoj`, i.e. I just switch the file extension. Now suppose I have an interrupted session and want to open all `.pdf` files in the directory provided that no corresponding `.xoj` file exists and open the `.xoj` file otherwise (both with `xournal`).

How can I do this in command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just remove `.pdf` to get the file's name without the extension and check for a file of that name with the `.xoj` extension:

```
for f in *.pdf
do
    if [ -f "${f%.pdf}".xoj ]
    then
        xournal "${f%.pdf}".xoj &
    else
        xournal "${f}" &
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for f in *.pdf; do
  fname=$(basename "$f" .pdf);
  if [[ -e "${fname}".xoj ]]; then
    # .xoj file does exist, do things here
  else
    # .xoj file doesn't exist, do other things here
  fi
done
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need the braces: `"$fname".xoj` (or `"$fname.xoj"` ) would be OK.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh` you could use the `e`*string* [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
for f (./*.pdf(.e_'[[ ! -f $REPLY:r.xoj ]] || REPLY=$REPLY:r.xoj'_))
xournal $f &
```

The string `[[ ! -f $REPLY:r.xoj ]] || REPLY=$REPLY:r.xoj` is  executed as shell code. `REPLY` holds the value of the current argument. If there's no corresponding `.xoj` file for the current `.pdf` file then `[[ ! -f $REPLY:r.xoj ]]` returns `true` and nothing happens (`REPLY` remains unchanged).
If there is a corresponding `.xoj` file for the current `.pdf` file then `[[ ! -f $REPLY:r.xoj ]]` returns `false` and `REPLY=$REPLY:r.xoj` is executed which replaces (via the `:r` modifier) the `.pdf` extension of the current argument with `.xoj`.

Answer (score -2):

Just trying to make it clear and concise. Re-assigning `f` and invoking xournal in only one place, accessing the extension mangling `${f%.pdf}` only once.

```
for f in *.pdf
do
    xoj = "${f%.pdf}.xoj"
    [ -f "$xoj" ] && f="$xoj"
    xournal "$f" &
done
```